# Screen corrupt when trying to use banner & interstitial ads in same app

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, banner-ads

I'm trying to show banner ads and interstitial ads via admob on different screens of my app. But every time I switch from the activity showing interstitial ad to activity showing banner ad my screen gets corrupted. It works fine when I use only one out of the two.

Seems like an admob issue. Anyone aware of any work around?

**Update** - 
*Banner Ad*

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        android:visibility="visible" />

public void onCreate(Bundle instance){
...
   mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
   mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
...
}
```

*Interstitial Ad*

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle instance){
   ...
   interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
       interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.full_screen_ad_unit_id));
       interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    finish();
                }
            });
       requestNewInterstitial();
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void showAd() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            finish();
        }

    }
```

[image: screenshot from device]

Comment: Show your code and layout

Comment: you are saying you have on both banner and inter and that causes the screen to corrupt? is it your layout getting messed up or the pop up inter?

Comment: the screen layout is getting messed after I come out of the Interstitial ad to the screen having banner ad. surprisingly the ad looks fine as you can see in the screenshot, only the app layout goes bad.

Comment: I tried your implementation, I created 2 activities, in first one i display interstitialAd, and when closed I moved to second screen and display your banner ads without any problem. If this is the scenario I will share code with you.

Comment: On which android and play services does this happen? On which device do you see this?

Comment: This seem some bug with Google Play services and issue only encounter in Lollipop OS. I have some time seen the same issue in Moto G running Lollipop and when I start the Native Google Map the screen has strange behavior.

Comment: Im using Android 5.0 on Motorola X2 with Google Play Services version 7.5.71. I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 5.0.1 and I dont see this problem in that device